# Error en el login de SQL Server Managment Studio 2018

Tags: sql-server, login

Tengo este problema al momento de querer iniciar en el login, al momento de instalarlo me abrió correctamente, pero ahora no me deja iniciar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando el usuario con permisos de administrador para iniciar sesión?
Qué forma de autentificación estás usando?
Revisaste que el nombre de usuario sea el correcto?
Con más info se podría ver la raíz del problema. Saludos!

Comment: Esto, más que una respuesta lo podrías poner como comentario.

Comment: Sí, es verdad. Gracias por el alcance